# com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement setDate: unable to persist proleptic Gregorian Calendar dates (for dates before 15 Oct 1582)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, gregorian-calendar

(Sorry for my english...)

To represent a gregorian calendar date before 15 Oct 1582 (starting date for Gregorian Calendar) it is possible to use a proleptic GregorianCalendar. Such a Calendar allows to represent dates prior to 15 Oct 1582 using the gregorian calendar system, also if it didn't exist at that time.
Two possible methods to create a new proleptic GregorianCalendar are the following (I report this for test purposes, but it is not essential):

```
    GregorianCalendar proleptic = null;
    
    proleptic = new GregorianCalendar();
    proleptic.clear(); 
    proleptic.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
    proleptic.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);
    proleptic.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
    proleptic.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1582);
    System.out.println("proleptic_calendar_8Oct1582 [DAY_OF_MONTH ["+proleptic.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"], MONTH ["+proleptic.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"], YEAR ["+proleptic.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"], in millis ["+proleptic.getTimeInMillis()+"]");
    
    
    GregorianCalendar prolepticFromXML = null;
    String newDate = "1582-10-08";
    DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory = null;
    try {
        datatypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
        prolepticFromXML = datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(newDate).toGregorianCalendar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println("prolepticFromXML_8Oct1582 [DAY_OF_MONTH ["+prolepticFromXML.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"], MONTH ["+prolepticFromXML.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"], YEAR ["+prolepticFromXML.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"], in millis ["+prolepticFromXML.getTimeInMillis()+"]");
    
    System.out.println("millis matches: ["+(proleptic.getTimeInMillis() == prolepticFromXML.getTimeInMillis())+"]
```

output:

```
proleptic_calendar_8Oct1582 [DAY_OF_MONTH [8], MONTH [9], YEAR [1582], in millis [-12219901200000]
prolepticFromXML_8Oct1582 [DAY_OF_MONTH [8], MONTH [9], YEAR [1582], in millis [-12219901200000]
millis matches: [true]
```

Now we imagine to receive a string from an input source (a web form, a soap request, etc) and to build with it a proleptic GregorianCalendar, we can call it *myCalendarField*, .
Then, I'd like to write this date on a mysql database, in a column of type DATE.
I use *Hibernate* as persistence framework and imagine the *myCalendarField* is a field mapped into an Entity class

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "a_test_date_field")
public Calendar getMyCalendarField() {
    return this.myCalendarField;
}
```

following the code starting by org.hibernate.type.CalendarDateType, that manages the mapping between java Calendar and sql DATE,  I found that it calls the method

```
public void setDate(int parameterIndex, java.sql.Date x, Calendar cal)
```

in *com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement*, available in the mysql connector,

passing a

```
new java.sql.Date( myCalendarField.getTime().getTime() );
```

as *x*

Now, the setDate method uses a SimpleDateFormat in order to convert the passed Date in string, prior to convert this string on byte[] and following the work-flow.
To format the date the connector does something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat ddf = new SimpleDateFormat("''yyyy-MM-dd''", Locale.US);
ddf.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone()); 
String timeString = ddf.format(x);
```

at this point the format method of java.text.SimpleDateFormat does something like this

```
Calendar calendar = null;
calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.US);
calendar.setTime(x);
```

and uses the new instantiated calendar to get all date and time informations to build the output formatted string.
What happens is then that the new created Calendar is not proleptic anymore, than the dates prior to 15 Oct 1582 are converted to julian dates.
As a consequence of this, we obtain on DB a date different from the one received in input.

So, if a java web application receives for example 8 oct 1582, treats it as a proleptic Gregorian Calendar and wants to save it on a DATE field on a mysql DB, the date persisted becomes 28 Sep 1582.
I found no way, at the moment, to persist the original input date without modifications.

Are my conclusions correct? Do you know any way to persist on a mySql DB a date prior then 15 Oct 1582 as proleptic GregorianCalendar, using Java + Hibernate + my sql connector?

**EDIT**
In 2018 the [jdbc connector bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72609), opened following this post, has been fixed.

Comment: Aside: bear in mind that the supported range of MySQL's `DATE` type is `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`, so if you might deal with historical dates earlier than year 1000, you will run into further problems there.

Comment: "myCalendarField" can be obtained in various ways. Generally it is received as String (e.g. submitted by a web form or obtained by a soap request). The conversion from string to Calendar can be done with a code similar to what I've shown in the first code extract, see "prolepticFromXML". But the way the field is obtained does not have any relevance since it is converted into java.sql.date and then formatted to String passing through a new Calendar, inside the  java.text.SimpleDateFormat...

Comment: Although the type sql DATE has the limitations that @eggyal has pointed out, you can still insert to the db dates before the year 1000. Anyway, the problem still exists between 1000-01-01 and 1582-10-15.

Comment: It seems to me that, having [constructed a `SimpleDateFormat` object](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/connectorj/5.1/view/head:/src/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java#L4791), MySQL Connector/J should then call `setCalendar()` upon it specifying a `GregorianCalendar` which has been set to be pure/proleptic Gregorian (i.e. with `setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE))` as you describe).  I have filed a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72609).

Comment: I can not find the instructions you are talking about, at the link that you posted. Could you tell me the exact line in the code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand. Thank you for the bug report.